# How to stop a thread by sending a signal

Tags: linux, pthreads, signals, signal-handling

Suppose a thread is running some code:

```
// thread
while (_running)                 // (1)
{
   rv = read(...);               // (2)
   // do something with data
}
```

We can add a signal handler to stop the thread:

```
// signal handler
_running = false;
```

And use `pthread_kill` to execute this handler on the thread. This would unblock the read at (2).

This approach has a race-condition:
If the signal handler executes between (1) and (2), the thread will not be stopped.

How can this race-condition be avoided?

Comment: Instead of using a blocking `read(...)` call you could check if something is ready to be read with `select`. You also make the `read` not-blocking with `fcntl`